# Why i can't put more than 1 setters of same argument type in class which implements genericHandler in dsl?

Tags: spring-integration

I have created a class implementing GenericHandler to use in .handle() method. I have setters for the class, but if i have more than 1 setter with same argument type, i am getting "Found Ambiguous parameter type".

Why there is such restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just because `ServiceActivatingHandler` is based on the `MessagingMethodInvokerHelper` logic on background to determine the appropriate *messaging* method. And setters are candidate for that purpose.
So, if you really hae several of them with the same param type, we end up with ambiguity issue.

To fix your case, I suggest mark your `Object handle(P payload, Map<String, Object> headers);` implementation with `@ServiceActivator`.

From other side I agree that it is not so good as we expect from Framework. So, feel free to raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INTEXT) issue on the matter and we will fix `.handle()` to be more strict and rely only on the `handle()` method from the `GenericHandler` implementation.

Comment: created an improvement issue in JIRA

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem while using Spring integration while using a service adaptor. Could not define multiple properties of type java.lang.String - I would get a IllegalArgumentException claiming "ambiguous parameters".

After finding no solution to the issue, decided to just create a class to encapsulate those properties, configure this as a bean, and then inject it into the spring-integration config.